# Auto-synch data in container upon changes in host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Is it possible to have a volume that is sort of "live synched" between the host and the container? My point is to have a `Node.js` app/project on the host machine, and then run a `node.js` container, which will pick up the project and then whenever I change a file in the project - it to get immediately updated in the container without having to restart the container in order for the volume to get copied.

Currently I have the source code copied in the container's volume upon lifting the container:

```
server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8001:1337"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: npm start
```

but, as you can see, I need to restart the container every time I want the changes to be updated from the host to the container.

If that is possible, could you provide an example how to write it in docker-compose and maybe also a link to the appropriate docs?

Comment: The volume mapping looks OK, that should actually sync the files between host and container (that's how I use it). If the node process (`npm start`) is the only reason why you need to restart the container, maybe take a look at something like [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) and use that as the `command` instead of `npm start`. In that case, nodemon should pick up the change in the file system and restart your node app.

Comment: Some more info: http://fostertheweb.com/2016/02/nodemon-inside-docker-container/

Comment: And here: https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/master/01-express-nodemon

Comment: @nwinkler, I actually do use `nodemon` :D I just masked it behind the `npm start` command, in my `package.json` file as follows: `"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js", ...}`

Comment: But my files do not really get updated. I will do some more tweaking and testing, with the info I'll find in the docs that you linked. I'll come with updates if anything works. :)

Comment: @nwinkler, it's all good in the hood now! :)

Comment: Good to hear - so what was the solution?